# HTML Table not showing first record of PostgreSQL

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I've managed to fill an HTML table with user queries from PostgreSQL without problem, the thing is that when I make the Query on the PostgreSQL database directly it shows the complete records according to the Query but when I do it in my PHP and fill an HTML with it it doesn't show the first one

For example I have 500 records and I want them in `DESC` order
It should show:

```
500
499
498
...
```

But it shows:

```
499
498
497
...
```

So its 'jumping' the first record always, with every query I call
What could it be? Obviously I need all the records.

Here is the code I'm using to run the query($sql1) and $conexion is the connection to my postgresql db:

```
$rs  =odbc_exec($conexion, $sql1);
$nr  =odbc_result($rs, 1);
if(!empty($nr)){
    print "
        <table width='992' border='1' class='Gtable'>
        <tr>
        <td width='46' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Codigo<strong</td>
        <td width='46' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Matricula</strong></td>
        <td width='100' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Municipio</strong></td>
        <td width='150' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Barrio</strong></td>
        <td width='80' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Concepto</strong></td>
        <td width='50' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Tipo Susp.</strong></td>
        <td width='200' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Observacion</strong></td>
        <td width='156' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Cliente</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Direccion</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Telefono</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>F.Grabacion</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Planificacion</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Inicio</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Finalizacion</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Efectiva</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Descripcion de Cierre</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Contratista</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Empleado</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>F.Cierre</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Genero</strong></td>
        <td width='151' bgcolor='#EEEDE8'><strong>Cerro</strong></td>
        </tr>";

        while($result =odbc_fetch_array($rs)){
                print "<tr>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['cod_otrb']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['cod_pred']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['descripcion']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['brdesc']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['tqdesc']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['cod_ttrb']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['spdesc']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['prnombre']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['direccion']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['telefono']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['fecha_grab']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['fecha_pla']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['fecha_ini_trb']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['fecha_pre_cierre']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['efectiva']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['otdesc']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['ctnombre']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['emnombre']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['fecha_cierre']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['usr_genera']."</td>
                    <td align='left' valign='top'>".$result['usr_cierra']."</td>
                    ";

        }
        print"</table>";
}else{
    print "<font color='#CC3333'><strong>No Hay Registros</strong></font>";
}
```

Comment: Are the record indexes zero-based (starting with zero)? If so, you would get 0 - 499 (500 records).

Comment: While I am not familiar with PostgreSQL/`odbc_*`, my guess is that `$nr  =odbc_result($rs, 1);` is pulling the first record (500), and moving the internal pointer to the next. So when you try to Loop the results, it is at the second record.

Comment: You may want to change that line to use [`odbc_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-num-rows.php) instead

Comment: @Sean odbc_num_rows() is not guaranteed to return a usable result on a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (as pointed out by @Sean in the comments) is that this line:

```
$nr =odbc_result($rs, 1);
```

is reading the first row from the result set and you are not outputting the data from that row. To work around this I would recommend an `if ... do ... while` structure:

```
if ($result = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    // output the table headers here
    do {
        // output the row data
    } while ($result = odbc_fetch_array($rs));
}
else {
    // no data to output
}
```